# Enumerate Keys in a dictionary?

Tags: dictionary, python-2.7

I have a dictionary

```
Dict = {'ALice':1, 'in':2, 'Wonderland':3}
```

I could find ways to return key values but there was no way to return key names.

I want Python to return the dictionary key names step by step (for loop) for example:

```
Alice
in
Wonderland
```

Comment: I might be tempted turn it into an appropriate list of value-key pairs and then sort based on value in this example and then iterate. (Remember that keys in dictionary are *not* ordered.)

Comment: Ordering is'nt a problem for me. I don't need it in a specific order. Im just trying to enter key names into SQL database.

Answer (score 22, accepted):

You can use `.keys()`:

```
for key in your_dict.keys():
  print key
```

or just iterate over the dictionary:

```
for key in your_dict:
  print key
```

Do note that dictionaries aren't ordered. Your resulting keys will come out in a somewhat random order:

```
['Wonderland', 'ALice', 'in']
```

---

If you care about order, a solution would be to use lists, which *are* ordered:

```
sort_of_dict = [('ALice', 1), ('in', 2), ('Wonderland', 3)]

for key, value in sort_of_dict:
  print key
```

Now you get your desired results:

```
>>> sort_of_dict = [('ALice', 1), ('in', 2), ('Wonderland', 3)]
>>> 
>>> for key, value in sort_of_dict:
...   print key
... 
ALice
in
Wonderland
```

Comment: `for key in your_dict.keys():` can be simplified to `for key in your_dict:`

Comment: @NolenRoyalty: Thanks! Dunno why I missed that.

Answer (score 2):

```
def enumdict(listed):
    myDict = {}
    for i, x in enumerate(listed):
        myDict[x] = i

    return myDict

indexes = ['alpha', 'beta', 'zeta']

print enumdict(indexes)
```

> prints: {'alpha': 0, 'beta': 1, 'zeta': 2}

**Edit: if you want the dict to be ordered use ordereddict.**

Comment: Not exactly an answer to the question but I upvoted as it is handy trick.

Answer (score 1):

dict has a keys() method.

Dict.keys() will return a list of keys, or use the iterator method iterkeys().